# How to deal with version conflicts in update by query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scenario where I run multiple update by queries before flusing the index. This result in various version conflicts.

The requirement is that i do not have to care about the previous version because if its being updated by a new query.

I am using `conflict=proceed` in my request because i don't want them to abort. However this is i am not sure that with the `conflict=proceed` option, the version conflict documents are actually being updated or rejected.

If Elasticsearch doesn't update a document if there is a version conflict, How can I get those particular matching documents and update them manually.

Example code:

```
foreach ($this->requests as $request) {
        $futures[] = $client->updateByQuery($request);
    }

    foreach ($futures as $future) {
        $future->wait();
        if ($future['version_conflicts'] > 0) {
            // How to get those documents which were rejected and update them manually. Since I always want to have the last version   
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: As a note, I am also having this problem, and did not found solution yet. But, what I noticed is, for some reason I am facing a lot of _version conflicts when XDEBUG is enabled_. Disabling XDEBUG on my dev env resulted to 0 conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

You could add your own `version` as new field:

1. Bulk update, to version 2
2. Search documents that match version 1
3. Update manually (and set to version 2)
4. Loop 2

Comment: This means elasticsearch does not update a document if there is a version conflict right ?